# How can I delay the route from screen A to B to be able to help in transition using react-router

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to implement a transitional routing to pages using react-router. How can I implement a time-out so several animations take place before I go to the next screen

I will paste some code:

App.jsx

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          {/* {({ match }) => ( */}
          <Transition in timeout={500}>
            {state => <SignIn state={state} />}
          </Transition>
          {/* })} */}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signup">
          <Transition timeout={500}>
            {state => <SignUpOptions state={state} />}
          </Transition>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/personal-info">
          <Transition timeout={500}>
            {state => <PersonalInformation state={state} />}
          </Transition>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signup-verification">
          <SignUpVerification />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Signin page

```
const SignIn = ({ state }: Props) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <ScreenDiv>
      <ImageContainer animateToLeft={state === 'entered'}>
        <ImageDivFemale />
      </ImageContainer>
      <FormDiv>
        <SignInInput placeholder="Username" />
        <SignInInput type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <SignUpButton
          style={{
            cursor: 'pointer',
          }}
        >
          {SIGN_IN}
        </SignUpButton>
        <ForgotUsernameParagraph>
          {FORGOT_USERNAME_PASSWORD}
        </ForgotUsernameParagraph>
        <SignUpParagraph
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
          onClick={() => {
            history.push('/signup');
          }}
        >
          {NO_ACCOUNT_YET}
        </SignUpParagraph>
      </FormDiv>
    </ScreenDiv>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

So when I press on {NO-ACCOUNT-YET} I want to delay the route to the '/signup' so I can apply css transitions. Also how can I trigger a css animate in css of the styled-component after onclick

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
onClick={
          () => { 
              setTimeout(() => {history.push('/signup')}, 500);
          }
        }
```